# Failed to connected MongoDB with server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I failed to connected MongoDB with server and the codes are given below, please concern below,

> app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

module.exports = app;
```

> .env:

```
MONGODB_SERVER = mongodb://localhost:27017/burger-builder
PORT = 3001
```

> server.js:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();
const app = require('./app');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_SERVER, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,

})
     .then(() => console.log('Connect to MongoDB!'))
     .catch(err => console.log('MongoDB Connection Failed!'));

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.listen(port, () =>{
     console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
})
```

**Please concern the attached file for checking the error.**

**Note:** In `.env` file I connected with the location as `burger builder` but there is no any file . Is it the main probel to failed the MongoDB with the server?

Comment: What error do you see?

Comment: please log the error  -> `.catch(err => console.log('MongoDB Connection Failed!', err.stack));`

Comment: make sure your mongodb is running in background.

Comment: console log the  process.env.MONGODB_SERVER , verify if its not empty

Answer (score 1):

1. Can you console log the error?
2. Can you make sure mongodb is running?
3. Can you make sure the uri is correct? port is correct?

Comment: Thanks a lot MongoDB was not running.